# Writing powershell functions within a string

Tags: powershell

If I have:

```
Write-Host "[$(Get-Date -displayhint time)] backup starting..."
```

I get:

```
[02/17/2010 1:26:12pm] backup starting...
```

i. e. the `Get-Date` parameters are being ignored and is just returning the output of `Get-Date`.

What's the best way to do inject the current time in the middle of a string?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, in this case you're converting to a string because you are using the output in a string. The result of the Get-Date command is still a DateTime object. The display hint would then be honored by the Out-Host cmdlet.

You can use the `-Format` parameter to force a certain format in which case the cmdlet returns a string:

```
Get-Date -Format T
```

(`"T"` being the format string for the full time) which then looks like this:

```
PS Home:\> Write-Host "[$(Get-Date -Format T)] backup starting..."
[19:35:12] backup starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ToString() method of the DateTime class. I usually do something like this:

```
[PS] C:\>write-host "$((get-date).tostring('yyyy.MM.dd-HH:mm:ss'))"
2010.02.19-09:54:51
```

Comment: The `-Format` parameter of `Get-Date` does exactly the same and looks much less cluttered, though :)